# SQL Server - Write a query that groups weeks data from Fri->Thurs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-date-functions

I am trying to separate data in my database from Thurs->Fri in the following way:

```
(Get last 10 weeks of data, grouped by Fri->Thurs as a week) e.g if today was 8/13/2018:

From (Fri)  To (Thur)
---------------------
8/10/2018   8/16/2018
8/3/2018    8/9/2018
7/27/2018   8/2/2018
7/20/2018   7/26/2018
7/13/2018   7/19/2018
7/6/2018    7/12/2018
6/29/2018   7/5/2018
6/22/2018   6/28/2018
6/15/2018   6/21/2018
6/8/2018    6/14/2018
```

I tried doing this by writing a query (more complicated than I like):

```
WITH Vars (d)
AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(week,-9, (DATEADD(day, - ((Datepart(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) +1) %  7) , GETDATE()))  ) As 'd' 
)
SELECT WeekNum+1  As [WeekNum], Count(*) Count
FROM
(
 SELECT (Datepart(Week, (DATEADD(day, - ((Datepart(WEEKDAY,t.DateField)+1 ) %  7), t.DateField)) ) )as WeekNum
 FROM Table as t
 WHERE (SELECT d FROM Vars) <= t.DateField

) as table

GROUP BY WeekNum
ORDER BY WeekNum ASC
```

But it group by's the wrong dates

How can I modify the query to return the correct data?

**NOTE** I want this to be a query and not a stored procedure of any kind if possible.

Comment: Do you have a calendar table? it could well make things much easier if so.

Comment: @Larnu Il look into that actually. It will make things easier, especially considering I have to write this in one transaction (query)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your query is the `DATEPART(WEEKDAY,...`. The weekday returned depends on your regional settings and is most probably using a Sunday as the start of a week.

To calculate the most recent Friday, you can use an expression like this (which does not depend on regional settings):

```
DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 4, GETDATE())/7, 4)
```

This makes use of the fact that SQL Server's "date 0" is 1/1/1900 (a Monday), so the "date 4" is 1/5/1900 (a Friday) and also takes advantage of DATEDIFF returning an integer, so dividing that by 7 is an *integer division*.

Assuming that your `WeekNum` works like desired, especially after a turn of the year, the query could be changed like this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(week, Friday)+1 AS WeekNum, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM
(
  SELECT DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 4, t.DateField)/7, 4) AS Friday
  FROM [Table] t
  WHERE t.DateField >= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 4, GETDATE())/7-9, 4)
) AS [table]
GROUP BY Friday
ORDER BY Friday
```

Also, you can easily display the dates, if you want:

```
SELECT Friday, DATEADD(day, 6, Friday) AS Thursday, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM ... -- same as above
```